# How to fix 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' error in while loop

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, anaconda, psychopy

Windows 10
Python 3.7
Anaconda 1.9.7
Spyder 3.3.3
PsychoPy for Python 2.7

I am coding an experiment that needs to present images in a random order for the participant to respond to. I am able to get the images in an array, but to present them one at a time I am using a while loop with a variable that increases by 1 every time it goes through the loop. It is not recognizing the variable as a number and therefore the array cannot call anything.

I've tried not randomizing the variable to see if that is the issue, but it just seems to be that my variable i is not being read as a number

```
#import packages
import random, os
from psychopy import core, visual, event
from PIL import Image

#setup screen with specs and draw
win = visual.Window([400, 300], monitor="testMonitor")
message = visual.TextStim(win, text="")

message.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(3.0)

#set image size and populate array with images
stim_size = (0.8, 0.8)
image = [i for i in os.listdir('C:/Users/*/psychopy-tests') 
                    if i.endswith('.bmp')]
#randomize image order
images = random.shuffle(image)
```

## this is where my issue seems to be

```
i = 0
while i != 29: #there are only 28 images
    
    new = images[i] #this is where the issue is
    image_stim = Image.open(new)

    stim = visual.ImageStim(win, image_stim, size = (stim_size))
    stim.draw()
    win.update()
    output = []
    if event.getKeys(keyList=['space']):
        output[i] = 1
    if event.getKeys(['escape']):
        win.close()
        core.quit()
    if event.getKeys(keyList=None):
        output[i] = 0
        core.wait(5.0)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: A few other notes: instead of this `while` do `for new in image:`. Then define `stim` above the loop and in the loop do `stim.image = new`. This will be faster and safer. No need for the variable `i` anymore then.

Comment: I can't show you the output, but removing `stim = visual.ImageStim(win, image, size = (stim_size))` from the loop prevents the images from being opened individually. I get the error "Couldn't make sense of requested image"

Comment: `images = random.shuffle(image)`  - shuffle shuffles in-place and returns None. unless you set `images` to some other thing later on there is no way that there is anything in it. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.shuffle .

Comment: if you only have 28 images, start with `i = 1` and increment until `while i != 29:` you are trying to do 29 images:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, etc: 0-9 == 10 images, 0-19== 20 images, 0-28 == 29 images

Answer (score 2):

The `random.shuffle` shuffles in place and doesn’t return anything i.e., It returns None.

Therefor `images` is None and not subscriptable.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: when I print out the shuffled array though it shows that it has worked corrected

Comment: is there any other function I can use?

Comment: You printed `images` and it worked? Not `image` but `images`?

Comment: I printed images separately yes and it returned my image list in a random order. Removing the randomization did not fix this problem "NoneType" as I said

Comment: I just tested. As a said the `images` will be None. I don't understand how did you manage to print a None object. Are you saying that you used `print(images)`  (plural)

Comment: yes, when I print(images) I got
LFN03.bmp', 'LFN10.bmp', 'LFP26.bmp', 'LFN19.bmp', 'LFN22.bmp', 'LFN27.bmp', 'LFP01.bmp', 'LFN14.bmp', 'LFP22.bmp', 'LFN07.bmp',  ect

Comment: do you have any other suggestions for randomization if you think this is the problem?

Comment: But if you managed to print them out why do you get the 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'. No I'm afraid I have no other suggestions.

Comment: I do not know, which is why i am posting. Even if I completely take out the `images = random.shuffle(image) line` and use `new = image[i]`, I receive a NoneType

Comment: Ok I tested again and it works on my side. If you managed to print `image` and got the list of names then the line `new = image[i]` can not throw a `None type exception` only `IndexOutOfRange Exception`. Are you sure the code you wrote here is updated to your code changes?